# Strip slashes from database request correctly

Tags: php, stripslashes

I have message stored in my database containing a slash: e.g. don\'t

To present the message I use this procedure. The thing is the backslash is still displayed.
How can I get rid of it.
I have tried many things, and read several postings here, but can't get it to work. Anyone here to help me and tell me what is the best way..

```
            $msg2 = html_entity_decode($row3[comment]);
            echo stripslashes(nl2br($msg2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When storing them in the database, you should store them as `mysql_real_escape_string($phpString)`.

Why do you use `html_entity_decode` for this? Just `stripslashes` should be sufficient here..